# MPAndroidChart v3.0.0-beta1 LineData constructor only takes 1 argument

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to follow this guide:

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data

It has the line of code:

```
LineData data = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);
```

When I tried it in my AndroidStudio, the LineData() constructor only takes 1 argument instead of 2 arguments as shown in the guide.

Anyone know how to initialize with the new version of MPAndroidChart ?

I have the following in my gradle setting:

```
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'
```

Maybe I should drop to 2.2.5 ?

### Update

Yes, I changed gradle to use 2.2.5 and now LineData() constructor has multiple parameters as expected.

Docs needs updating for version 3.0.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartActivity1.java. It might be helpful.

Comment: Doesn't show me how to add horizontal labels, he only added a list of entries that's it.

Comment: I manage to download the zipped project which has a example app with all the graphs for version 3.0. I am now able to render the graph using version 3.0, still trying to understand how the labels are generated though o.O

Comment: Great.... Actually I haven't checked new library version 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

in this version

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
```

try it

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LineChart lc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initView();
    initData();
}

public int ran() {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int i = ran.nextInt(199);

    return i;
}

public int ran2() {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int i = ran.nextInt(49);

    return i;
}

public void initData() {
    lc.setExtraOffsets(12,50,24,0); //padding
    setDescription("two lines example");
    lc.animateXY(500, 0);
    setLegend();
    setYAxis();
    setXAxis();
    setChartData();
}

public void setLegend() {
    Legend legend = lc.getLegend();
    legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
    legend.setFormSize(20);
    legend.setTextSize(20f);
    legend.setFormLineWidth(1);
    legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    legend.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}

public void setDescription(String descriptionStr) {
    Description description = new Description();
    description.setText(descriptionStr);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(outMetrics);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    float x = outMetrics.widthPixels - Utils.convertDpToPixel(12);
    float y =  Utils.calcTextHeight(paint, descriptionStr) + Utils.convertDpToPixel(12);
    description.setPosition(x, y);
    lc.setDescription(description);
}

public void setYAxis() {
    final YAxis yAxisLeft = lc.getAxisLeft();
    yAxisLeft.setAxisMaximum(200);
    yAxisLeft.setAxisMinimum(0);
    yAxisLeft.setGranularity(10);
    yAxisLeft.setTextSize(12f);
    yAxisLeft.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    yAxisLeft.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return value == yAxisLeft.getAxisMinimum() ? (int) value + "" : (int) value +"";
        }
    });
    lc.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
}

public void setXAxis() {
    XAxis xAxis = lc.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(20);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    xAxis.setTextSize(12f);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1);
    xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(100);

    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return value == 0 ? "example" : (int) value + "";
        }
    });
}

public void setChartData() {

    List<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int j = ran();
        yVals1.add(new Entry(1 + i,j));
    }

    List<Entry> yVals2 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int j = ran2();
        yVals2.add(new Entry(1 + i,j));
    }

    LineDataSet lineDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(yVals1, "ex1");
    lineDataSet1.setValueTextSize(20);
    lineDataSet1.setDrawCircleHole(true);
    lineDataSet1.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    lineDataSet1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.LINEAR);
    lineDataSet1.setDrawCircles(true);
    lineDataSet1.setCubicIntensity(0.15f);
    lineDataSet1.setCircleColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    lineDataSet1.setLineWidth(1);

    LineDataSet lineDataSet2 = new LineDataSet(yVals2, "ex2");
    lineDataSet2.setValueTextSize(20);
    lineDataSet2.setDrawCircleHole(true);
    lineDataSet2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    lineDataSet2.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.LINEAR);
    lineDataSet2.setDrawCircles(true);
    lineDataSet2.setCubicIntensity(0.15f);
    lineDataSet2.setCircleColor(Color.BLUE);
    lineDataSet2.setLineWidth(1);

    .
    .
    .

    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();

    dataSets.add(lineDataSet1);
    dataSets.add(lineDataSet2);

    LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSets);

    lc.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5);
    lc.setScaleXEnabled(true);
    lc.setData(lineData);
}
```

and like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.0 is initialized like so:

```
LineChart lineChart = new LineChart(context);

lineChart.setMinimumHeight(ToolBox.dpToPixels(context, 300));
lineChart.setMinimumWidth(ToolBox.getScreenWidth());

ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<>();    

for(int i = 0; i < frigbot.getEquipment().getTemperatures().size(); i++)
    {
        Temperature temperature = frigbot.getEquipment().getTemperatures().get(i);

        yVals.add(new Entry(
                i, temperature.getValue().floatValue()
        ));
    }

LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(yVals, "graph name");
dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
dataSet.setCubicIntensity(0.2f);

LineData data = new LineData(dataSet);

lineChart.setData(data);
```

It appears we can't specify custom horizontal labels, LineChart itself will automatically generate the horizontal and vertical axis labelling.